# How do I read from a GZIPInputStream in Xamarin.android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a an Array of bytes byteArray which contains data compressed with Gzip. I want to read the whole array and decode the data using the appropriate encoding ("ISO-8859-15").

```
GZIPInputStream gzipInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(new MemoryStream(personalDataArray));
InputStreamReader inputStream = new InputStreamReader(gzipInputStream);
```

However I get a compiler error when trying to read the gzip input stream with an Input stream reader, it says cannot convert from `Java.Util.Zip.GZipInputStream` to `System.IO.Stream`. This issue does not occur in Java though. How do I get around this? How do I specify the encoding to be used too? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method to decompress GZip, use `GZipStream`

Here you have Xamarin doc. about [System.IO.Compression.GZipStream Class](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.IO.Compression.GZipStream/)

```
 static byte[] Decompress(byte[] data)
    {
        using (var compressedStream = new MemoryStream(data))
        using (var zipStream = new GZipStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        using (var resultStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            zipStream.CopyTo(resultStream);
            return resultStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

And you can read it using `Encoding.UTF8.GetString()`,

```
var msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Decompress(personalDataArray));
```

Also You have to convert UTF-8 to ISO-8859-15 (Latin9), this sample is for ISO-8859-1 (Latin1), but try with ISO-8859-15.

```
var strISO88591= Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")
                 .GetString(Encoding.Conver‌​t(Encoding.UTF8,Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg)));
```